# NSMutableURLRequest get -1012 http status code instead of 401

Tags: objective-c, post, http-status-codes, nsmutableurlrequest

I have to pass Authorization token in NSMutableURLRequest , My query is Whenever I have to pass Correct token than I am getting good response with https Status (200.. etc). but whenever I have to pass wrong Authorization token Than I am getting following response insted of http status code 401

*** with wrong token response *** (I had hide my query htpp:....)

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http......, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800024c420 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey={url = http.....}}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http....}

** here is my code **
       // parameter in dictionary

```
   NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"user_id": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]};

   NSError *error;
   NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];

   // Convert dictionary to Json String

   if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    jsonparameter = jsonString;

}

NSData *postData = [jsonparameter dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:SiteAPIURL,wsname]]];

    NSString *Accesstoken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",tokenInfo.access_token];

    // Set Access token 

    [request setValue:Accesstoken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSHTTPURLResponse __autoreleasing *response;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
NSLog(@"Status code =%ld",(long)response.statusCode);
```

Comment: Completely unrelated, but (a) you don't have to set `Content-Length` header as that's done for you; (b) it's unnecessary to take `jsonData`, convert it to a string and then convert it back to a `NSData`. Just set `HTTPBody` to be `jsonData`; (c) unless you need to support OS versions predating `NSURLSession`, you should really retire `NSURLConnection` and not do synchronous requests.

Comment: You did not receive a -1012 status code. That is the error code, which is `NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`. You’re confusing the error with the status code that you print on the next line. What was a status code printed after the error?

Comment: after error I am getting Status code = null

Comment: OK, then clearly the authorization error is preventing the `NSHTTPURLResponse` from capturing any status code.

Comment: Can you please explain briefly , What I do to get http status code 401 ?, Thanks

Comment: I get a 401 when I try to login to a web server with BASIC authentication using `URLSession` but supply incorrect (or no) credentials. I don't know if you're not seeing 401 because you're using `URLConnection` or because your server is using BEARER authentication. (I'd guess the latter.) I guess if you know how to detect this (error code `NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication`), isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

401 is server generated error. -1012 is system generated error. This sometimes may be because of app is keeping cached certificates and certificate on the server has been changed so they don't match. Clearing `Caches` and `Preferences` folders from app's `home directory` will delete the old certificate data and app will have to download the new one from the server and you problem will be solved.